# Play a video when entering hover, then a gif while still on hover, and then another video when leaving hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, gif

I'll have a button in the middle of the screen.
when the user hovers over it, a video will start playing in the background. When the video is over, a gif will instantly start playing and keep on playing as long as the user still hovers over the button. At last, when the user leaves the hover - yet another video will play.
TLDR:

- button on hover
- video plays
- video ends
- gif playing (nonstop until next step)
- button not on hover
- another video plays
- video ends

I want to wow my teachers and would love some help :D
the videos and gifs in question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aThg2.jpg

Thanks again!

EDIT: I hope this didn't come out wrong, I'm looking for a hint - not for someone to code all of that himself. Maybe a function, or a piece of advice; something to code from.

Comment: I have a built website, I want to add it to a section of it. Also just looking for a hint, not really asking anyone to code all of that himself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints...

Assuming you have a good knowledge of HTML and Javascript already,

I'd use the `<video>` tag to embed your video, an `<img>` tag for a gif. 
Use the onmouseover and onmouseout events to track the mouse movements and change the innerHTML content of your button when needed!

Something like that should work!

Comment: I'm kinda new to JS, but Ill try nonetheless! I'll edit the post if I can make it work.

Comment: First get something working just to change the content of the button, use text, get the mouse controls working first then think about adding the video content. If you get stuck with part of it, you can ask a more specific question and show people your code.

Comment: I tried it with text: https://jsfiddle.net/w5ouxcpn/ I think that the challenge is going to be to control the videos and gifs since I've never done something like that before.

Comment: Nice start! Here's the fun thing with timeouts though, look what happens if you move the mouse in, out and in again quickly! :)

Comment: It goes crazy xD I hope that it won't happen with the gifs. I'll try it with innerHTML now :)

Comment: ;)  So, you need something to keep track of whether your timeout actions have started, what should be happening etc, also if you mouseout before your mouseover actions have finished, what then?

Comment: I see... it needs to skip the middle gif and quickly switch between the opening and ending, and only when its more than the duration of the opening - the middle gif will play. Hmm, any way to do that?

Comment: It depends what you want to happen when you mouseout. Do you want the video to finish? Do you want it to cancel? If you only want the gif to play once the video has finished if you're still hovering, then you need a separate timeout and function to check if the mouse is still there. You also need to check on mouseout that the mouseover functions have finished.

Comment: I've been trying for some time but seems like I can't get rid of this issue  :"D Gotta practice some JS.

Comment: I got bored and did half of it for you ;) 
https://jsfiddle.net/21gpodkq/2/

Comment: :O Thanks! I also got something but its half working, left hope that it'll be fully working lmao

Comment: What is the 'function startGif() {

  }' for?

Comment: I put a few functions in as structure. Think of each function as a part of the whole process. You have to get them to trigger at the right times. Feel free to change it as you like. Your gif will run when the video finishes, right? So startGif is the next step in the process.

Comment: So I decided to change the videos to gifs for an easier time, and I tried adding a counter that can tell me if the user stayed on hover long enough for the second stage to continue - this doesn't work :"D. What I get is that the middle gif (that runs while on hover) flickers, then the background flickers, and then we're back to normal. Here's where I'm at so far: https://jsfiddle.net/wsdt2qob/1/

Comment: You don't need the counter function. Just use timeouts to start your video, then start the gif. Use the videoPlaying and hovering variables to make sure the functions don't re-trigger when they are already in progress. Also stick to text until it's working, it's easier to work with. If you post more code can you include the HTML too please.